# using Tkinter to create Fireworks

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a very nice-colorful Firework using Tkinter (python), Although it did not worked for me. The Problem is that the Firework particles in the explosion(Rocket class) part are not stoping and i have no clue why . I've already tried many things however it did not get any better .

**Note : the Class i'm talking about called Rocket where the Particle move  and the exploed and does not stop "exploding" ** - i used Particle class and Firework class, so you wouldn't need to read all the code just those parts .

My Code :

```
import tkinter as tk
from time import time, sleep
from random import choice, uniform, randint
from math import sin, cos, radians
from sys import modules

GRAVITY = 30  # you can play around with this if you want

class Particle:
    """Generic class for particles.

    Particles can be emitted by Fireworks objects. They are displayed for a
    specified lifespan and then removed from the canvas.

    Attributes:
        cv (Tk.canvas): the canvas in which the particle is drawn.
        cid (Tk.canvas): the tkinter canvas id for the particle.
        x (float): x-coordinate of the particle.
        y (float): y-coordinate of the particle.
        vx (float): x-velocity of the particle (in pixels per second).
        vy (float): y-velocity of the particle (in pixels per second).
        color (str): color of the particle.
        age (float): age of the particle.
        lifespan (float): lifespan of the particle (in seconds).

    """

    def __init__(self, cv=None, color='white', x=0., y=0.,
                 vx=0., vy=0., lifespan=5.):
        """Init Particle objects.

        Args:
            cv (Tk.canvas): the canvas in which the particle is drawn.
            x (float): x-coordinate of the particle.
                Defaults to 0.0.
            y (float): y-coordinate of the particle.
                Defaults to 0.0.
            vx (float): x-velocity of the particle (in pixels per second).
                Defaults to 0.0.
            vy (float): y-velocity of the particle (in pixels per second).
                Defaults to 0.0.
            color (str): color of the particle.
                Defaults to 'white'.
            lifespan (float): lifespan of the particle (in seconds).
                Defaults to 5.0.

        """
        self.cv = cv
        self.cid = None
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        self.vx, self.vy = vx, vy
        self.color = color
        self.age, self.lifespan = 0, lifespan

    def update(self, dt):
        """Update position and velocity after dt seconds have passed.

        Args:
            dt (float): the time that has passed after the last update (in s).

        """
        self.age += dt
        if self.alive():
            self.vy += GRAVITY * dt
            self.x += self.vx * dt
            self.y += self.vy * dt
            self.cv.move(self.cid, self.vx * dt, self.vy * dt)
        elif self.cid is not None:
            cv.delete(self.cid)
            self.cid = None

    def alive(self):
        """Check if particle is still within its lifespan."""
        return self.age <= self.lifespan


class SquareParticle(Particle):
    """A Particle with a quadratic shape"""
    def __init__(self, x=0., y=0., size=2., **kwargs):
        super().__init__(x=x, y=y, **kwargs)
        self.cid = self.cv.create_polygon(
            x - size, y - size, x + size, y - size,
            x + size, y + size, x - size, y + size,
            fill=self.color)


class TriangleParticle(Particle):
    """A Particle with a triangular shape"""
    def __init__(self, x=0., y=0., size=2., **kwargs):
        super().__init__(x=x, y=y, **kwargs)
        self.cid = self.cv.create_polygon(
            x - size, y - size, x + size,
            y - size, x, y + size,
            fill=self.color)


class CircularParticle(Particle):
    """A Particle with a circular shape."""
    def __init__(self, x=0., y=0., size=2., **kwargs):
        super().__init__(x=x, y=y, **kwargs)
        self.cid = self.cv.create_oval(
            x - size, y - size, x + size,
            y + size, fill=self.color)


class Fireworks:
    """Generic class for fireworks.

    The main "behavior" of a fireworks is specified via its update method.
    E.g., new particles can be emitted and added to the particle list. The
    Fireworks base class automatically updates all particles from the particle
    list in its update method.

    Attributes:
        cv (Tk.canvas): the canvas in which the fireworks is drawn.
        age (float): age of the fireworks.
        particles (list of Particle): list of generated particles.

    """

    def __init__(self, cv=None):
        """Init Fireworks objects.

        Args:
            cv (Tk.canvas): the canvas in which the particle is drawn.

        """
        self.cv = cv
        self.age = 0
        self.particles = []

    def update(self, dt):
        """Update the fireworks' particles and remove dead ones.

        Args:
            dt (float): the time that has passed after the last update (in s).

        """
        self.age += dt
        for p in self.particles:
                 p.update(dt)
        for i in range(len(self.particles) - 1, -1, -1):
            if not self.particles[i].alive():
                del self.particles[i]


class Volcano(Fireworks):
    """A volcano that continuously emits colored particles.

    Attributes:
        x (float): x-coordinate of the volcano.
        pps (float): the number of particles to spawn per second.
        colors (list of string): the colors of the particles to spawn."""

    def __init__(self, cv, x, pps, colors):
        """Init Volcano objects.

        Args:
            cv (Tk.canvas): the canvas in which the particle is drawn.
            x (float): x-coordinate of the volcano.
            pps (float): the number of particles to spawn per second.
            colors (list of string): the colors of the particles to spawn.

        """
        super().__init__(cv)
        self.cid = cv.create_polygon(x - 12, 530,  # size and color are fixed
                                     x + 12, 530,  # (can be parametrized)
                                     x, 500,
                                     fill="orange")
        self.x = x
        self.pps = pps
        self.colors = colors
        self._tospawn = 0

    def update(self, dt):
        """Continuously emits new random particles and updates them.

        Args:
            dt (float): the time that has passed after the last update (in s).

        """
        super().update(dt)
        self._tospawn += self.pps * dt
        color = self.colors[int(self.age / 3) % len(self.colors)]
        for i in range(int(self._tospawn)):
            ptype = choice(
                [SquareParticle, TriangleParticle, CircularParticle])
            angle = uniform(-0.25, 0.25)
            speed = -uniform(80.0, 120.0)
            vx = sin(angle) * speed
            vy = cos(angle) * speed
            self.particles.append(
                ptype(cv=self.cv, x=self.x, y=500, color=color, vx=vx, vy=vy))
        self._tospawn -= int(self._tospawn)


class Rocket(Particle, Fireworks):

    def __init__(self, cv, x=0., y=0., size=2., **kwargs):
        super().__init__(cv, x=x, y=y, **kwargs)
        self.cid = self.cv.create_oval(
            x - size, y - size, x + size,
            y + size, fill=self.color)
        self.x = x
        self.pps = 100
        self.colors = ['red']
        self._tospawn = 0
        self.particles = []

    def update(self, dt):
        self.age += dt
        if self.alive():
            self.vy += -GRAVITY * dt
            self.x += self.vx * dt
            self.y += self.vy * dt
            self.cv.move(self.cid, self.vx * dt, self.vy * dt)
        elif self.cid is not None:
            cv.delete(self.cid)
            self.cid = None
        if self.cid is None:
             Fireworks.update(self, dt)
             color = self.colors[int(self.age / 3) % len(self.colors)]
             self._tospawn += self.pps * dt
             for i in range(int(self._tospawn)):
              ptype = choice(
                [CircularParticle])
              angle = uniform(-100, 100)
              speed = -uniform(80, 120.0)
              vx = sin(angle) * speed
              vy = cos(angle) * speed
              self.particles.append(
                 ptype(cv=self.cv, x=self.x, y=self.y, color=color, vx=vx, vy=vy))
              self._tospawn -= self.pps * dt


def simulate(cv, objects):
    """Fireworks simulation loop.

        Args:
            cv (float): the canvas in which the firework objects are drawn.
            objects (float): the firework objects.

    """
    t = time()
    while running:
        sleep(0.01)
        tnew = time()
        t, dt = tnew, tnew - t
        for o in objects:
            o.update(dt)
        cv.update()


def close(*ignore):
    """Stops simulation loop and closes the window."""
    global running
    running = False
    root.destroy()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = 10
    root = tk.Tk()
    cv = tk.Canvas(root, height=600, width=800)
    cv.create_rectangle(0, 0, 800, 600, fill="black")  # sky
    cv.create_rectangle(0, 450, 800, 600, fill="gray11")  # ground
    cv.pack()

    v1 = Volcano(cv, 400, 100, ["red", "green", "gold"])
    ro = Rocket(cv, 600, 500)
    objects = [v1, ro]

    # close with [ESC] or (x) button
    root.bind('<Escape>', close)
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", close)

    running = True
    root.after(500, simulate, cv, objects)
    if "idlelib" not in modules:
        root.mainloop()
```

For me it is more important to unterstand why that's happened , so it would be very nice if i get explanation within .

Comment: use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what values you have in variables.

Comment: I run code and Rockec stops only when I move window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Rocket` I had to move

```
self._tospawn += self.pps * dt
```

into

```
elif self.cid is not None:
```

to stop fireworks

```
   elif self.cid is not None:
        cv.delete(self.cid)
        self.cid = None

        self._tospawn += 10 * self.pps * dt

   if self.cid is None:
        Fireworks.update(self, dt)
        color = self.colors[int(self.age / 3) % len(self.colors)]
        for i in range(int(self._tospawn)):
          ptype = choice(
            [CircularParticle])
          angle = uniform(-100, 100)
          speed = -uniform(80, 120.0)
          vx = sin(angle) * speed
          vy = cos(angle) * speed
          self.particles.append(
             ptype(cv=self.cv, x=self.x, y=self.y, color=color, vx=vx, vy=vy))
          self._tospawn -= self.pps * dt
```

You can move all except `Framework.update()`

```
   elif self.cid is not None:
        cv.delete(self.cid)
        self.cid = None

        self._tospawn += 10 * self.pps * dt

        color = self.colors[int(self.age / 3) % len(self.colors)]
        for i in range(int(self._tospawn)):
          ptype = choice(
            [CircularParticle])
          angle = uniform(-100, 100)
          speed = -uniform(80, 120.0)
          vx = sin(angle) * speed
          vy = cos(angle) * speed
          self.particles.append(
             ptype(cv=self.cv, x=self.x, y=self.y, color=color, vx=vx, vy=vy))
          self._tospawn -= self.pps * dt

   if self.cid is None:
        Fireworks.update(self, dt)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir , that's really helps

Comment: any explanation for that ?

Comment: `Rocket.update()` is executed in `while running` all the time. It sets `self.cid = None` so it starts execute `if self.cid is None:` all the time, and if sets `self._tospawn += self.pps * dt` again and again. It means that `for i in range(int(self._tospawn)):` creates new particles again and again. Even `self._tospawn -= self.pps * dt` can't stop it. But if you move `self._tospawn += self.pps * dt` to `elif self.cid is not None:` then it will be set only once, `for` will be executed only once and `self._tospawn -= self.pps * dt` will reset it so next time `for` will not create new particles.

Comment: thanks sir , one more question is it possible to create a class that repeat the Rocket class many times , in other words creating random Fireworks not just one but many ? if it is possible can you please explain

Comment: do you mean more Rockets or one Rocket with more Fireworks. More Rockets you can create on start and add to `objects = [v1, ro]`. Or you can create some `RocketsLaucher` with method `update()` so you could add to `objects = [v1, ro, laucher]` and it will execute its `laucher.update()` in `simulate` as `o.update()`. It will need access to `objects` so it could add new `Rocket` to this list.

Comment: so basically in the [update() ] i should refer to the Rocket class . right ?

Comment: @furas Do you know how to start a rocket after a specific time? In this example, the rocket starts as soon as the vulcano starts. I would like to create more rockets and add them to the ```objects = []```.list. The problem: All of them start at the same time. Am I able to change that? And if yes, where do I need to add some code? THank you very much!

Comment: @lefrcom this question has 3 years I don't remeber this code but normally tkinter uses `root.after(milliseconds, function_name)` to execute function with delay - so you could use it to run function which add Rocket to the list.